# Undefined reference to `TRandom3::Rndm(int)` and `_gfortran_...` symbols

Tags: c++, linux, linker, fortran, root-framework

I'm trying to compile an example program to understand how garfield++ works (that I want to use to simulate a drift tube).
I've just installed garfield++ and I've downloaded the example program at the bottom of this page http://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/examples/tube/ then I've done the `make` command but I've received the following errors:

```
roberto@roberto-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Scrivania/Garfield$ make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long `root-config --cflags` -O3 -fno-common -c -I/home/roberto/garfield/Include -I/home/roberto/garfield/Heed gasfile.C
gasfile.C:12:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
     ^
gasfile.C:12:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
g++ -o gasfile gasfile.o `root-config --glibs` -lGeom -lgfortran -lm -L/home/roberto/garfield/Library -lGarfield
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(Medium.o): nella funzione "Garfield::Medium::GetElectronMomentum(double, double&, double&, double&, int&)":
Medium.cc:(.text+0xf0b4): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
Medium.cc:(.text+0xf0fb): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(Medium.o): nella funzione "Garfield::Medium::GetElectronCollision(double, int&, int&, double&, double&, double&, double&, int&, int&, int&)":
Medium.cc:(.text+0xf1ea): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
Medium.cc:(.text+0xf231): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(MediumMagboltz.o): nella funzione "Garfield::MediumMagboltz::ComputePhotonCollisionTable(bool)":
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x4cd1): riferimento non definito a "TMath::Voigt(double, double, double, int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(MediumMagboltz.o): nella funzione "Garfield::MediumMagboltz::GetPhotonCollisionRate(double const&)":
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x24913): riferimento non definito a "TMath::Voigt(double, double, double, int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(MediumMagboltz.o): nella funzione "Garfield::MediumMagboltz::ComputeDeexcitationInternal(int, int&)":
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x25319): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x2533e): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x25387): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x255da): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x256ca): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(MediumMagboltz.o):MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x25746): seguono ulteriori riferimenti non definiti a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(MediumMagboltz.o): nella funzione "Garfield::MediumMagboltz::GetPhotonCollision(double, int&, int&, double&, double&, int&, double&)":
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x26fa8): riferimento non definito a "TMath::Voigt(double, double, double, int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x2703d): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x270ef): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
MediumMagboltz.cc:(.text+0x2730d): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(RandomEngineRoot.o): nella funzione "Garfield::RandomEngineRoot::RandomEngineRoot()":
RandomEngineRoot.cc:(.text+0x2c): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::TRandom3(unsigned int)"
RandomEngineRoot.cc:(.text+0xbe): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::~TRandom3()"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(RandomEngineRoot.o): nella funzione "Garfield::RandomEngineRoot::~RandomEngineRoot()":
RandomEngineRoot.cc:(.text+0xf6): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::~TRandom3()"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(RandomEngineRoot.o): nella funzione "Garfield::RandomEngineRoot::Seed(unsigned int)":
RandomEngineRoot.cc:(.text+0x175): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::SetSeed(unsigned int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(RandomEngineRoot.o): nella funzione "Garfield::RandomEngineRoot::Draw()":
RandomEngineRoot.cc:(.text._ZN8Garfield16RandomEngineRoot4DrawEv[_ZN8Garfield16RandomEngineRoot4DrawEv]+0x12): riferimento non definito a "TRandom3::Rndm(int)"
/home/roberto/garfield/Library/libGarfield.a(magboltz.o): nella funzione "master.0.rm48_":
magboltz-9.01.f:(.text+0x29f): riferimento non definito a "_gfortran_st_write"
magboltz-9.01.f:(.text+0x2b3): riferimento non definito a "_gfortran_transfer_character_write"
magboltz-9.01.f:(.text+0x2c7): riferimento non definito a "_gfortran_transfer_integer_write"
magboltz-9.01.f:(.text+0x2db): riferimento non definito a "_gfortran_transfer_integer_write"
magboltz-9.01.f:(.text+0x2ef): riferimento non definito a "_gfortran_transfer_integer_write"
```

Where `riferimento non definito` is the Italian for `undefined reference to`. I can't understand the problem because in the Makefile there is a link to gfortran.
If I do:

```
roberto@roberto-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ root-config --glibs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic
```

Comment: You should include more log. At the very least the compilation or linking command called by the make that caused the error.

Comment: This is the makefile http://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/examples/tube/makefile

Comment: I wanted the message, not the makefile (although it can help). And put in in the question, not a link somewhere.

Comment: I put the entire log in a pastebin link in the question.

Comment: All relevant info should be **in the question itself**. Not doing so is a reason for closure of the question.

Comment: I can't insert the log in the message because it's longer than the maximum number of characters, so I use pastebin.

Comment: Welk, then extract only the relevant parts, no-one is going to read it all. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them?cb=1 why links are so bad.

Comment: Ok, I've done the changes.

Comment: There ae some more symbols missing there, not just from gfortran. Some of them come from some C++ library.

Comment: Yes, but in the makefile there are the links to all the libraries that are used in the program, as you can see in the log.

Comment: For example in `g++ -o gasfile gasfile.o ``root-config --glibs`` -lGeom -lgfortran -lm -L/home/roberto/garfield/Library -lGarfield` Which of those libraries is sopposed to contain `TRandom3`? Check your ROOT configuration.

Comment: I don't know exactly, because I never used root before, but if I do `roberto@roberto-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Scrivania/Garfield$ locate TRandom3` I get `/usr/include/root/TRandom3.h` and for that I think that must be in root-config --glibs, if I do `roberto@roberto-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Scrivania/Garfield$ root-config --glibs` I get `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic`

Comment: Add the output of `root-config --glibs`.

Comment: Added to the question.